# pip. No module named. Ошибка в виртуальной среде

Tags: python, pip

Нужно создать виртуальную среду. Делаю так.

Перехожу в папку

```
cd /d F:\PyTorch\ProjectDepth
```

Устанавливаю виртуальную среду venv в директории.

```
python -m venv PDepth1
```

Запускаю виртуальную среду venv.

```
PDepth1\Scripts\activate
```

после команд с pip получаю ошибку из заголовка. pip.exe есть в структуре папок  виртуалки. Что делаю не так?

Полный код ошибки

```
(PDepth1) F:\PyTorch\ProjectDepth>pip.exe install requests

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Programs\Python3.7.9\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)

  File "C:\Programs\Python3.7.9\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)

  File "F:\PyTorch\ProjectDepth\PDepth1\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Не получается и через интерпретатор.

```
(PDepth1) F:\PyTorch\ProjectDepth>python -m pip install requests
F:\PyTorch\ProjectDepth\PDepth1\Scripts\python.exe: No module named pip
```

В питоне pip стоит. У pip последняя версия установлена.

Comment: `python -m pip install requests`. Лучше не вызывать `pip` напрямую. Интерпретатор `python` лучше знает где отыскать модуль `pip` совместимый с ним (интерпретатором).

Comment: Да, пробовал по разному вызывать.

(PDepth1) F:\PyTorch\ProjectDepth>python -m pip install requests
F:\PyTorch\ProjectDepth\PDepth1\Scripts\python.exe: No module named pip

Comment: Выглядит так что у вас не полная установка `python`. Без модуля `pip`. `pip.exe` - это пустышка, которая исполняет `python -m pip ...` и больше ничего не делает. Ищите что не так с инсталляцией.

Comment: Инсталляцией, вы имеете в виду виртуальную среду? Есть ли возможность посмотреть что там должно быть?

Comment: Нет. Я имел в виду что когда вы ставили `python` инсталлятором вы не поставили галочки отвечающие за установку `pip`. Или установка `python` повреждена. Или установлены два питона двух разных версий а пути к ним смешаны в PATH (в итоге первый питон ищет пакеты в втором каталоге или наоборот).